# Date picker UI breaks randomly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, datepickerdialog

I am opening Android date picker on a dialog using custom style.
This implementation is working as expected but sometime it displays unexpected UI.

Below is my code:

Style:

```
<style name="datepicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/header_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/header_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/header_color</item>
</style>
```

Activity:

[image: Activity screenshot]

```
dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
    currentCtx,
    R.style.datepicker,
    dateSetListener,
    jsonDate.year,
    jsonDate.month,
    jsonDate.day
);
```

Comment: remove title of datedialog using 

dateDialog.setTitle("");

Comment: Title is nullable, so we can use datedialog.setTitle(null) to remove title.

Comment: setTitle is not working. Also this extra header is coming only when the selected date and max date is equals. Any solutions?